# Unverified breakpoint in flutterapp in vscode.How can I overcome this issue?

Tags: flutter, debugging, visual-studio-code, breakpoints, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug my code in Visual Studio Code, but I am getting the `Unverified breakpoint` message on my breakpoint, and execution does not stop on my breakpoint.These breakpoints are automatically generated.On clicking a line break points are automatically enabled.
}
[image: t]

Comment: whats the reason for setting a breakpoint in line `SizedBox(height: 20),` ?

Comment: if you tell the line number. Why breakpoints on function arguments? What assembler instruction is generated for an argument? You can only put a breakpoint on lines that executes something

Comment: @pskink Im not set these breakpoints, it automatically generated.How can I solve this issue?

Comment: automatically? what you mean by that?